# Displaying the last two digits of the current year in Java

Tags: java, date-formatting, gregorian-calendar

How can I display only the last two digits of the current year without using any substring algorithms or any third party libraries?

I have tried the below method and it gave a four-digit year. I want to know whether there are any date formatting options available to get the current year in two-digit format.

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format a date as per your requirements.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yy"); // Just the year, with 2 digits
String formattedDate = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

**Edit:** Depending on the needs/requirements, either the approach suggested by me or the one suggested by *Robin* can be used. Ideally, when dealing with a lot of manipulations with the Date, it is better to use a `DateFormat` approach.

Answer (score 77):

You can simply use the modulo operator:

```
int lastTwoDigits = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) % 100;
```

*Edit: Using a `SimpleDateFormat`, as @R.J proposed, is the better solution if you want the result to be a string. If you need an integer, use modulo.*

Comment: Seems like a clever solution at first but will result in a 1 digit number for years such as "2001" or 0 if it's like "2100"

Answer (score 16):

This is a one-liner:

```
    System.out.println(Year.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uu")));
```

I am using `java.time.Year`, one of a number of date and time classes introduced in Java 8 (and also backported to Java 6 and 7). This is just one little example out of very many where the new classes are more convenient and lead to clearer code than the old classes `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

If you just wanted the two-digit number, not as a string, you may use:
`Year.now().getValue() % 100`.

The other answers were good answers in 2013, but the years have moved on. :-)

Edit: New Year doesn’t happen at the same time in all time zones. To make the dependency on time zone clear in the code I would usually write `Year.now(myDesiredTimeZoneId)`, for example in the form `Year.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())`.

Answer (score 4):

[`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) also has [Date/Time Conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#dt).

To get the last two digits of the current year,

```
String.format("%ty", Year.now());
```

This works with a number of the `java.time` classes, including `Year`, `YearMonth`, `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

**In Kotlin**

Call this function and pass time in parameter

> Example :
> Input Parameter : "2021-08-09T16:01:38.905Z"
> Output : 09 Aug 21

```
private val inputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
private val outputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")

        fun calculateDateMonthYear(time: String): String {
            val inputTime = inputFormat.parse(time)
            val convertDateMonthYear = outputFormat.format(inputTime!!)
            val timeInMilliseconds = outputFormat.parse(convertDateMonthYear)!!
            val mTime: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            mTime.timeInMillis = timeInMilliseconds.time
            val date_cal = SimpleDateFormat("dd")
            val month_date = SimpleDateFormat("MMM")
            val year_cal = SimpleDateFormat("yy")
            val date = date_cal.format(mTime.time)
            val month_name = month_date.format(mTime.time)
            val year = year_cal.format(mTime.time)
            return "$date $month_name $year"
        }
```

Comment: Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class had severe design problems and has been outdated the last 10 years. Use java.time as shown in a couple of the answers. It works great in Kotlin too (or may consider kotlin.time, which is inspired by java.time). In addition hardcoding `Z` as a literal in the format pattern is wrong. `Z` is an offset of 0 and needs to be parsed and formatted as an offset to get correct results.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @Robin Krahl is a bit hacky but I like it. We could avoid the cases commented by @Albert Tong if we add a leading zero. In order that we have the last two digits of the year, I suppose that the result should be a String. In case we could not use the solution of @jaco0646. We could do this:

```
 String yearStr = addLeadingZero(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) % 100)

 private String addLeadingZero(int num) {
   String result = String.valueOf(num);
    if(num < 10){
        result = "0" + result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question asked for how to do this in Java but Google sent me here when asking about Groovy, so I'll add my answer for that here.

I came up with this based on the Java answer provided by Rahul:

```
String lastTwoYearDigits = new Date().format("yy")
```